# Nodegroups are recreated (as number replica needs to match)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

How to safely delete node from the cluster?

Firstly, I have drained and deleted the node.
However, after few seconds kube created again. I believe its because of the cluster service, where number of replicas are defined.
Should i update my cluster service and delete ?
Or is there any other way to safely delete ?

Answer (score 1):

**To delete a node and stop recreating another one automatically follow the below steps:**

1. First drain the node

   `kubectl drain <node-name>`
2. Edit instance group for nodes (using kops)

   `kops edit ig nodes`
3. Finally delete the node

   `kubectl delete node <node-name>`
4. Update the cluster (using kops)

   `kops update cluster --yes`

Note: If you are using a pod autoscaler then disable or edit the replica count before deleting the node.